# Standard form Shor's code

Tags: error-correction, textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang

I'm trying to solve exercise 10.57 in Nielsen-Chuang, where you have to obtain the standard form check matrix of Shor's code. I followed the procedure laid out in the earlier chapter but then realised that applying the Gauss-Jordan method seems to leave a negative value on my $Z$-side.

How to interpret this, or have I just made a mistake? Here's my result:
$$\begin{bmatrix} \left.\begin{matrix}
 1&  0&  1&  1&  1&  0&  0&  0&  1\\
 0&  1&  0&  1&  1&  1&  0&  1&  1\\
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0
\end{matrix}\right|
\begin{matrix}
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  1&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  1&  0&  0&  0&  0&  -1\\
 0&  0&  0&  0&  1&  0&  0&  0&  1\\
 1&  0&  0&  0&  0&  1&  0&  0&  0\\
 0&  1&  0&  0&  0&  0&  1&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  1&  0
\end{matrix} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Haven't verified your matrix, but note that linear algebra in this context is taking place over the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so you should not be worried about -1 since -1=1.

Comment: Thanks, that's the information I was looking for.

Comment: I think you do have errors - all the Z-rows should have even weight.

Answer (score 1):

My result is
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccccccc|ccccccccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$

---

Edit:

Start from
$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccccc|ccccccccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]$$
Swap qubit 2 and 6
$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccccc|ccccccccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]$$
Put the bottom two rows to the top and shift the rest.
$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccccc|ccccccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
\right]$$
Finally, use Gaussian elimination to get the standard form.

Cheers.

Comment: Please add additional information, e.g. how you reached these results.

Comment: @MartinVesely Added